# Install a certificate (SSL Encryption) on SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, ssl, certificate

I found some manual here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898/ru
but can't make a step with :

> The Certificate Request Wizard dialog
>   box opens. Click Next. Select
>   Certificate type is "computer".

On "Registration politics" step there is Active Directory registration politic by default and so it requests some registration server ... I got no some reg server , I just want to make some certificate and add it to my MS SQL 2005 Express

I also created some certificates using IIS, but when I setup it on my MSSQL Server fails to start at the end of starting with error like "Wrong query or service is inaccessible, see system log"

Also there was some manual about using makecert utility, but my MSSQL saw not certificate I created using this tool like

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN= MySQLServerName" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 
-eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange 
-sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

so maybe I'm doing wrong or you got something helpful about my task : how to Install a certificate (SSL Encryption) on SQL Server 2005 Express ?

finally : sorry for my English and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the properties of the certificate which you create are OK. The usage of `-sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12` switches are not needed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx#sectionToggle2. You should verify that the host name of the server where SQL Server are running is MySQLServerName. A blanks between CN and the hostname or DNS name are not needed (use "CN=MySQLServerHostName").

You should also verify that you installed certificate which you created in "Trusted Root Certification" certificate store of the local computer on the server where SQL Server are running.

If you have an error during SQL Server start could you post the exact error message from the evenl log or from the ERRORLOG (from the directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log or something like that)